# Where can I find the buildinfo.sh file?

Tags: android, linux

I'm trying to find the buildinfo.sh and I didn't find it.
Does anyone know where is it and how can I access it.

Comment: Why exactly are trying to find/access this file?

Comment: I need it because the Arabic version of android 2.3 has Bug over there..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the source it's in [build/tools](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/tools/buildinfo.sh).

Comment: Lol thanks..Arabic language on android 2.3 has bug over there and I would like to see where is it.  I'm not pretty good programmer but I like to discover things to learn. Thanks agian

Answer (score 2):

the buildinfo.sh file is under [build/tools](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/tools/)